# Why python request works, but not the when make the same request in curl it does not

Tags: python, http, curl

I am trying to make a request from a saved session of my LinkedIn account to send a message however when I use the "curl" request, it does not work. Yet, when I use the python requests version it works right away. I am unsure of what is wrong with my "curl" request.

#### Python Code:

```
import requests
import json

reqUrl = "https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/messaging/conversations?action=create"

headersList = {
 "Host": "www.linkedin.com",
 "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0",
 "Accept": "application/json",
 "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
 "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
 "Referer": "https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=ali&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=HnO",
 "x-restli-protocol-version": "2.0.0",
 "X-LI-Lang": "en_US",
 "X-LI-Track": "{"clientVersion":"1.12.9","mpVersion":"1.12.9","osName":"web","timezoneOffset":5,"timezone":"Asia/Karachi","deviceFormFactor":"DESKTOP","mpName":"voyager-web","displayDensity":1,"displayWidth":1920,"displayHeight":1080}",
 "X-li-page-instance": "urn:li:page:d_flagship3_search_srp_people;zn3gn3MTTl6ilgF+0KG8hA==",
 "Csrf-Token": "ajax:your session",
 "Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8",
 "Content-Length": "489",
 "Origin": "https://www.linkedin.com",
 "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
 "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
 "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
 "TE": "trailers" 
}

payload = json.dumps({
  "keyVersion": "LEGACY_INBOX",
  "conversationCreate": {
    "eventCreate": {
      "value": {
        "com.linkedin.voyager.messaging.create.MessageCreate": {
          "attributedBody": {
            "text": "message",
            "attributes": []
          },
          "attachments": []
        }
      }
    },
    "recipients": [
      "ACoAACAAZBIBVTrxu7umYeGDknEvSHy6CbWpFGI"
    ],
    "subtype": "MEMBER_TO_MEMBER"
  }
})

response = requests.request("POST", reqUrl, data=payload,  headers=headersList)

print(response.text)
```

The same curl version does not work. Strage

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://www.linkedin.com/voyager/api/messaging/conversations?action=create' \
  --header 'Host: www.linkedin.com' \
  --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/110.0' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
  --header 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  --header 'Referer: https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=ali&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL&sid=HnO' \
  --header 'x-restli-protocol-version: 2.0.0' \
  --header 'X-LI-Lang: en_US' \
  --header 'X-LI-Track: {"clientVersion":"1.12.9","mpVersion":"1.12.9","osName":"web","timezoneOffset":5,"timezone":"Asia/Karachi","deviceFormFactor":"DESKTOP","mpName":"voyager-web","displayDensity":1,"displayWidth":1920,"displayHeight":1080}' \
  --header 'X-li-page-instance: urn:li:page:d_flagship3_search_srp_people;zn3gn3MTTl6ilgF+0KG8hA==' \
  --header 'Csrf-Token: ajax:your session' \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  --header 'Content-Length: 489' \
  --header 'Origin: https://www.linkedin.com' \
  
  --header 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  --header 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  --header 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  --header 'TE: trailers' \
  --data-raw '{
  "keyVersion": "LEGACY_INBOX",
  "conversationCreate": {
    "eventCreate": {
      "value": {
        "com.linkedin.voyager.messaging.create.MessageCreate": {
          "attributedBody": {
            "text": "message",
            "attributes": []
          },
          "attachments": []
        }
      }
    },
    "recipients": [
      "ACoAACAAZBIBVTrxu7umYeGDknEvSHy6CbWpFGI"
    ],
    "subtype": "MEMBER_TO_MEMBER"
  }
}'
```

What is the difference between both of the requests? Please provide an explanation for why one works and for why another does not work

Comment: Don't post passwords and/or *long living cookies*. They might be used for some sort of attack.

Comment: You should really anonymise your question; remove any live cookies/PIIs

Comment: That Python code certainly does not work as is, as it has syntax errors.

Comment: @deceze after fixing those errors it works, both codes are auto generated. Python code works.

Comment: What is the error you get with curl?

Comment: It returns Bad request.

Comment: Are you sure Content-Length is correct? Requests possibly calculates it itself (and overrules the given value); I'm not sure if Curl does that as well?

Comment: but, should not it be same for python and curl, it's same in the both requests.